# Android app is not visible in mobile app store but from browser its is availabe

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have uploaded the android app in the android app store. The app is not visible from the mobile app store but from my browser it is visible.

The devices I have tried:
GT-S5360  (Samsung) gingerbread
A60 (Micromax)  gingerbread

The *AndroidManifest.xml* code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hyperwebenable.techpanels"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/sitelogo"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".MessageList"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category
        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"  >
  </activity>
  <meta-data android:name="com.mobclix.APPLICATION_ID"
      android:value=""/>
  <activity
      android:name="com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixBrowserActivity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could cause a problem, but your uses-sdk is defined twice (with a different minSdkVersion). Try removing the second one.